# Converter objeto Java para JSON com Gson (gerando com barra invertida)

Tags: java, json, gson

Estou tentando gerar um JSON tendo como base um objeto Java.

O JSON está sendo gerado, porém algumas barras foram incluídas indevidamente:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Documento implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @SerializedName("Identificador")
    private String identificador;

    public Documento (){}

    public Documento (String identificador){
        this.identificador = identificador;
    }

    public String getIdentificador() {
        return identificador;
    }

    public void setIdentificador(String identificador) {
        this.identificador = identificador;
    }
}

String identificador = jsonObjResposta.getAsJsonArray("ListaObjetos").iterator().next().getAsJsonObject().get("Identificador").toString();

Documento documento = new Documento(identificador);

System.out.println("gson.toJson(documento): " + gson.toJson(documento));
```

Saída:

> ```
> gson.toJson(documento): {"Identificador":"\"bene1\""}
> ```

---

OBS: Vi que na verdade o `identificador` obtido do `jsonObjResposta` está vindo com as aspas, mas não consigo removê-la.

Comment: Seixas, parace que ele esta realizando o "escape" da string. Tente instanciar o objeto desta forma e valide se deu certo `Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().disableHtmlEscaping().create();`

Comment: Fiz um teste aqui e ficou sem a barra: `{"Identificador":"bene1"}`. Usei a versão 2.8.5 do Gson e criei ele com `new Gson()`. Poderia **[edit]** a pergunta colocando como o objeto `Gson` é criado e/ou alguma outra configuração que vc está usando? Veja também se é este documento que causa o problema, pois `\"` só seria usado se o identificador tivesse aspas nele.

Comment: JoãoManolo e hkotsubo, obrigado pelo retorno imediato. Eu alterei a pergunta, após fazer o teste com uma string, funcionou. Mas estou criando o novo objeto com uma informação obtida de outro json, nesse caso não funciona. Poderiam me ajudar? Valeu!!!

Comment: Bom, qual o valor da string `identificador`? Pois eu acho que ela está vindo com as aspas - palpite, porque vc não disse o que tem no `jsonObjResposta` :-) Uma dica geral é pensar que as outras pessoas aqui não têm o mesmo contexto que vc (que é o único que tem a visão geral do seu sistema). Nós só sabemos o que vc nos diz, e vc não diz o que tem nas variáveis, só nos resta adivinhar... Enfim, meu palpite é que o `identificador` está vindo com aspas (imprima o valor dele para conferir)

Comment: @hkotsubo, você está correto, me desculpe. A string está recuperada com aspas, não estou conseguindo alterar as aspas com replace, vou ter que percorrer toda string mesmo para substituir?

Comment: Para remover todas as aspas, é só fazer `identificador = identificador.replaceAll("\"", "")` (vai remover **todas** as aspas, o que parece ser o caso)

Comment: Peço desculpas aos amigos que prontamente me ajudaram por inicialmente ter postado a pergunta incorreta. @hkotsubo, perfeito, sua solução resolveu o meu problema. Posta a sua resposta para que eu possa marcar como solução.  Muito obrigado a todos. Valeu!!!

Comment: @Seixas Só editei a pergunta para que minha resposta faça um pouco mais de sentido e não pareça "adivinhação". Se discordar da edição, é só desfazê-la :-)

Comment: @hkotsubo Show!!! Tá perfeito!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fiz um teste básico com a versão 2.8.5 do Gson:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Documento documento = new Documento("bene1");

System.out.println("gson.toJson(documento): " + gson.toJson(documento));
```

A saída ficou sem as aspas:

> ```
> gson.toJson(documento): {"Identificador":"bene1"}
> ```

Pelos [comentários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/346975/converter-objeto-java-para-json-com-gson-gerando-com-barra-invertida?noredirect=1#comment698219_346975) vimos que na verdade a `String` original estava vindo com as aspas, então uma solução seria simplesmente removê-las, usando [`replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-):

```
// remove as aspas do identificador
identificador = identificador.replaceAll("\"", "");
```